# Application onCreate not called when application is using ForegroundService

Tags: java, android, kotlin, oncreate

My app is starting bounded ForegroundService at application startup (in MainActivity onCreate). When I stop ForegroundService by calling

```
stopForeground(true);
stopSelf();
```

inside this Service and `unbindService` in MainActivity onDestroy() then remove application from background (swipe out from task manager) and launch application again, Application onCreate() is not called.
I see that my application process still exists in system. Is it normal behaviour ? I'm a little surprised I didn't have chance to work with ForegroundService so far :)
Is it possible to kill application permanently ?

Comment: If app you're swiping from recents has foreground service running its still considered "in use" and only activitys task stack is destroyed while leaving process itself intact.

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/all-about-auto-start-foreground-service-in-android-8bba7569123e